# Attach USB cable to printer and now the case of my laptop has a voltage - Ouch

Tags: usb, laptop, printer

With my laptop on battery (e.g. nothing else connected to it), I hooked up a USB cable from my laptop's Dell Dock box to an older Xerox laser printer.

And now I am getting tingly zaps from the laptop case! (it is a Dell XPS13, so metal case, and I am barefoot on a tile floor). This isn't five or ten volts. I bet it is 40+ (sorry to say I have a lot of experience in this sphere... ouch!)

Bad cable?

Bad printer?

What to do? (I need to print!)

(The house is in Israel and is wired European style: Outlets are generally not grounded.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the electrical wiring.
Most likely, there is an issue with the earthing in your house.

better check with an electrician to avoid further damages.

Comment: Although a bit poorly worded, it is indeed likely that the printer is not connected to a grounded power socket. Although this will not cause for damage, it is inconvienient because it can create electric shocks. Not all homes have grounded sockets everywhere, especially older houses. This is an upgrade I always recommend when people move to a new home, and is also something I recommend people do to their current home. I've upgraded all my sockets to grounded ones, but only the kitchen and the computer area are important ones. Maybe the TV corner too.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to quantify "tingly zaps".

On an ungrounded device, such as the printer connected to two-wire mains, there can be a small amount of capacitive coupling between the "hot" side and the case -- I have a Toshiba with two-wire power block that produced a mild "tingle", at *very* low current, when I touched the case. That mild nuisance was fixed by AC-grounding through a capacitor.

On the other hand, the printer might be connected so that the case is actually connected to the hot lead, a potentially (NPI) **fatal** issue!

If the printer mains plug is non-polarized, try reversing it in the socket. However, it would be best to check **carefully** the current between case and a true earth ground, e.g., using a voltmeter with a 100 kΩ resistor across it. **Do not hold both leads!** If the reading is more than a few volts AC, then get a qualified electrician to fix the issue! Standard Israeli [SI 32 **grounded** outlets should be installed](https://www.plugsocketmuseum.nl/Israeli1.html).

Comment: OP enhanced to quantify "tingly zaps"  -- Thank you!

Comment: The **voltage** is not a safety issue. One can get a 10,000 V shock walking on carpet on a dry day (1 cm spark) without any issue. Again, the AC **current** measured across a known resistor shows amount of danger. 10 mA across skin can prevent letting go of a wire: https://www.elcosh.org/document/1624/888/d000543/section2.html